# Multiple searching of the same elements in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, optimization

There are perfomanse problems with bubbling subscribing via jQuery. IE9 and IE11 tell that 80% of time are spent on executing `querySelectorAll`. Analisis shows the function `$.event.dispatch` (in jQuery 1.8.1, in newer version (1.11.3) this functionality was moved to `$.event.handlers`), which containes following code:

```
for ( cur = event.target; cur != this; cur = cur.parentNode || this ) {

  // Don't process clicks (ONLY) on disabled elements (#6911, #8165, #11382, #11764)
  if ( cur.disabled !== true || event.type !== "click" ) {
    selMatch = {};
    matches = [];
    for ( i = 0; i < delegateCount; i++ ) {
      handleObj = handlers[ i ];
      sel = handleObj.selector;

      if ( selMatch[ sel ] === undefined ) {
        selMatch[ sel ] = jQuery( sel, this ).index( cur ) >= 0;
      }
      if ( selMatch[ sel ] ) {
        matches.push( handleObj );
      }
    }
    if ( matches.length ) {
      handlerQueue.push({ elem: cur, matches: matches });
    }
  }
}
```

Attension to following lines:

```
// For each element from clicked and above
for ( cur = event.target; cur != this; cur = cur.parentNode || this ) {
    // Clear the search cache
    selMatch = {};

    // For each subscriber
    for ( i = 0; i < delegateCount; i++ ) {
      // Take the subscriber's selector
      sel = handleObj.selector;

      // If it's out of cache
      if ( selMatch[ sel ] === undefined ) {
        // Search for elements matching to the selector
        // And remember if current element is among of found ones
        selMatch[ sel ] = jQuery( sel, this ).index( cur ) >= 0;
```

As the subscription is made on body, every such search takes all elements matching the selector from the whole document. And this is repeated as many times as the depth of the clicked element.

As I understand, the outer loop is to garantee write order of handlers according to bubbling order. There is a cache, but it works only at one level and helps in case of multiple subscription with the same selector.

The question is why cache is implemented in such manner? Why not to keep the jQuery collection and move `index` to the next `if` condition?

---

But that's not all. I looked the actual implementation in 1.11.3. It also uses multiple seaches but this line of code is changed.

In 1.8.1 it was:

```
selMatch[ sel ] = jQuery( sel, this ).index( cur ) >= 0;
```

In 1.11.3 it have become:

```
matches[ sel ] = handleObj.needsContext ?
jQuery( sel, this ).index( cur ) >= 0 :
jQuery.find( sel, this, null, [ cur ] ).length;
```

Same modification in this case doesn't seem to be reasonable.

---

So, the questions are:

1. What reason could've lead to this not optimal code?
2. What should I do to solve perfomance problems?

---

The following snippet shows the problem.

If you open the browser console and click `Click me to get a lot of searches!`.
you'll see following lines outputted 21 times:

```
qsa [id='sizcache041783330822363496'] section .smth
gbc smth-other
```

About the segment `[id='sizcache041783330822363496']` there is a [related question in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/465128/178988). Shortly, such form simplifies escaping of special characters in id if it was original. Some time ago Sizzle [has updated this place](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/commit/1a8958f6bc25ffb1ff2a1306ffd28d0539f93f84), but even actual jQuery version doesn't contain it.

```js
$(function () {
  $("body")
  .on("click", "section .smth", function () { console.log("clicked", "section .smth") })
  .on("click", ".smth-other", function () { console.log("clicked", ".smth-other") });

  $("h1").text("Click me to get a lot of searches!");

  var qsa = Element.prototype.querySelectorAll, gbc = Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName;
  Element.prototype.querySelectorAll = function(s) { console.log('qsa', s); return qsa.apply(this, arguments) };
  Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName = function(s) { console.log('gbc', s); return gbc.apply(this, arguments) };
});
```

```css
body { counter-reset: lev 1; }
div { counter-increment: lev; }
h1, h2 { cursor: pointer; }
h1:hover, h2:hover { background: silver; }
h1:after { content: " (" counter(lev) ")"; }
```

```html
<div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><h1>
  Loading...
</h1></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>

<section>
  <h2 class="smth">I'm smth and i'm waiting for a click</h2>
</section>

<section>
  <h2 class="smth-other">I'm smth other and i'm waiting for a click</h2>
</section>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
```

---

The next snippet shows the full code of jQuery 1.8.1 `dispatch` function (snippet is used to make collapsible spoiler, it's not for running the code):

```js
dispatch: function( event ) {

  // Make a writable jQuery.Event from the native event object
  event = jQuery.event.fix( event || window.event );

  var i, j, cur, ret, selMatch, matched, matches, handleObj, sel, related,
    handlers = ( (jQuery._data( this, "events" ) || {} )[ event.type ] || []),
    delegateCount = handlers.delegateCount,
    args = [].slice.call( arguments ),
    run_all = !event.exclusive && !event.namespace,
    special = jQuery.event.special[ event.type ] || {},
    handlerQueue = [];

  // Use the fix-ed jQuery.Event rather than the (read-only) native event
  args[0] = event;
  event.delegateTarget = this;

  // Call the preDispatch hook for the mapped type, and let it bail if desired
  if ( special.preDispatch && special.preDispatch.call( this, event ) === false ) {
    return;
  }

  // Determine handlers that should run if there are delegated events
  // Avoid non-left-click bubbling in Firefox (#3861)
  if ( delegateCount && !(event.button && event.type === "click") ) {

    for ( cur = event.target; cur != this; cur = cur.parentNode || this ) {

      // Don't process clicks (ONLY) on disabled elements (#6911, #8165, #11382, #11764)
      if ( cur.disabled !== true || event.type !== "click" ) {
        selMatch = {};
        matches = [];
        for ( i = 0; i < delegateCount; i++ ) {
          handleObj = handlers[ i ];
          sel = handleObj.selector;

          if ( selMatch[ sel ] === undefined ) {
            selMatch[ sel ] = jQuery( sel, this ).index( cur ) >= 0;
          }
          if ( selMatch[ sel ] ) {
            matches.push( handleObj );
          }
        }
        if ( matches.length ) {
          handlerQueue.push({ elem: cur, matches: matches });
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Add the remaining (directly-bound) handlers
  if ( handlers.length > delegateCount ) {
    handlerQueue.push({ elem: this, matches: handlers.slice( delegateCount ) });
  }

  // Run delegates first; they may want to stop propagation beneath us
  for ( i = 0; i < handlerQueue.length && !event.isPropagationStopped(); i++ ) {
    matched = handlerQueue[ i ];
    event.currentTarget = matched.elem;

    for ( j = 0; j < matched.matches.length && !event.isImmediatePropagationStopped(); j++ ) {
      handleObj = matched.matches[ j ];

      // Triggered event must either 1) be non-exclusive and have no namespace, or
      // 2) have namespace(s) a subset or equal to those in the bound event (both can have no namespace).
      if ( run_all || (!event.namespace && !handleObj.namespace) || event.namespace_re && event.namespace_re.test( handleObj.namespace ) ) {

        event.data = handleObj.data;
        event.handleObj = handleObj;

        ret = ( (jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler )
            .apply( matched.elem, args );

        if ( ret !== undefined ) {
          event.result = ret;
          if ( ret === false ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Call the postDispatch hook for the mapped type
  if ( special.postDispatch ) {
    special.postDispatch.call( this, event );
  }

  return event.result;
},
```

PS: [Same question in Russian.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476703/178988)

Comment: I did not quite get your question here. Are you trying to improve your code or jquery js code?

Comment: @pratikwebdev, any of them. As you see, the only place to optimize in my code is selector for the subscription. Replacing composite selector via just a class will cause calling `getElementsByClassName` instead of `querySelectorAll` - I expect this to be improvement, but it'll still be called multiple times. The other way of my code improvement is to subscribe on document and check `event.target` myself - but it doesn't seem to be a good solution. So I'd like to know about other ways of optimizations including changing jQuery code.

Comment: I got your point. I did some performance improvements before for Ie8, 9 & 11. I faced similar issues too and moreover related to querySelectorAll. from my personal experience its usually associated to developer code. If you could update your question with your code and what are you trying to achieve with it that may help to understand the issue better. Also I would suggest when you do performance analysis make sure that time consideration is only for code that you are trying to improve and not for the whole page or multiple actions performed. I assume you would have done it already.

Comment: @pratikwebdev, I've just actively clicked 2 inputs at depth 14 and got Ie9 unresponsive for more then a mitute with 80% (53sec) profiled as `querySelectorAll`. Analizing these calls I found that for each click I get 14 searches for `[id='sizcache041783330822363496'] .some-class .some-other-class` and the do NOT match with clicked elements, so no my code is called from these places. The page contains a few thousands of elements. There was also a bit of other code executed, but it was not even shown on the top profile lines.

Comment: What is the desired functionality? I mean you have multiple sections with h1 elements inside with someClass names. When user clicks on search link/h1 element you want to search for all matching elements with particular class? In general if code is going to do search based on class name and in your case if there are many elements matching class name it will take time. One thing you could do is if you know element containing those section elements bind your event to closest element to it rather than on body/document.

Comment: @pratikwebdev, headers are just a demo. In rteal code I have some plugins. I do not need to search them - they can be handled independently. And the do not have small enought container.

Comment: it is interesting. Would you be able to draft small example on JSFiddle?

Comment: @pratikwebdev, example of what? For example, a few collapsible blocks are handling bubbling of clicking their `.head`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98616/discussion-between-pratikwebdev-and-qwertiy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lifted the line with caching:

```
if ( delegateCount && !(event.button && event.type === "click") ) {
    selMatch = {};
```

and moved call to `index` from cahing to the next condition:

```
if ( selMatch[ sel ] === undefined ) {
    selMatch[ sel ] = jQuery( sel, this );
}
if ( selMatch[ sel ].index( cur ) >= 0 ) {
    matches.push( handleObj );
}
```